# What are the latest versions of the ARFoundation and ARKit XR Plugins can I use that still work with azure spatial anchors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-spatial-anchors

I'm working with Spatial Anchors for the first time. I have my own AR projects where I'm using different versions of the ARFoundation package (both verified and preview) and the ARKit XR Plugin. I would like to use the latest preview versions of the ARFoundation (3.1 preview 1)and the ARKit XR Plugin (3.1 preview 1) packages. I wanted to know if ASA should still be compatible or if I need to work with an earlier version? If so, why one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try of course, but it is likely something will break if you're using a more recent version of the AR packages than the ones ASA are scaled up to. I concur that it's not always immediately clear whether one can update the AR packages or to which version from the Git or Documentation.

What you can do to make sure is check the manifest file in the Github samples to see what version of the packages they have active, and go from there. It's a JSON you can find under *projectname*\Unity\Packages. [Link to current ASA manifest file on Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/blob/master/Unity/Packages/manifest.json)

These are the ones currently listed

- "com.unity.xr.arcore": "2.2.0-preview.2",
- "com.unity.xr.arfoundation": "2.1.4",
- "com.unity.xr.arkit": "2.1.1",

Hope this helps,
LazyNoodle

Comment: Thank you, LazyNoodle. This helps a lot. Happy Holidays!